# Changing invisible (white font) output in RStudio theme `Cobalt`

Tags: css, r, rstudio

I'm using R Studio's `Cobalt` theme, and I have found one case where in-line output in Rmd files is invisible (i.e. font is white on a white background). I would like to edit that font colour to anything visible.

Reproducible example below:

- First set Editor Theme to `Cobalt`:

[image]

Then, a simple example of using `str_view()` from Hadley's R4DS, in an Rmd file:

```
x <- c("apple", "banana", "pear")
stringr::str_view(x, "an")
```

The output will render to visible HTML no problem, and the Viewer window also shows visible output:

[image]

But when if you run it as an in-line chunk (i.e. how a lot of my debugging takes place), we get some of the output as a white font on white background:

[image]

How can I edit that font colour for that particular output, so that it is visible?

I have already tried editing Cobalt here:
https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Cobalt

Following the advice from here:
https://towardsdatascience.com/customize-your-rstudio-theme-914cca8b04b1

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's late but i've a solution with same problem.You need to change foreground color of your preferred theme(or change html background)

Here is you can edit your preferred theme : https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com

As you wrote upward,in most of dark themes foregrounds are whitish . Where you can edit in general tab .You should choose a bit darker foreground (for ex:#BEC0C2).[image]

or

i couldn't find how to change html background in Cobalt theme but some other (ex: Material) theme allow us to change colors of popup Css[image]

Sorry for my photo edits :D
Hopefully it will work ...

Comment: Thank you. Just to clarify, can you help me which field you would edit to edit the foreground color or the HTML background? I see both FG and BG, but I am not sure which ones to edit. If you're able to take a screenshot that's even better. Thanks again

https://tmtheme-editor.herokuapp.com/#!/editor/theme/Cobalt

Comment: i did edit my answer ,hopefully it will work for you

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking at this question, I've tried a lot of things, and honestly the easiest answer was to move the output of chunks out of the inline document, and move it to the console. Everything works after that:

[image]